# Require password for ssl user certificates every time

Tags: security, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I get this screen when I login in using my SSL user certificate:

[image]

However, I am **not** asked for the certificate password nor my phone's pin.

How can I make Android require me to enterSSLpassword or pin every time I use my SSL user certificate?

Comment: The screenshot is asking you to install the certificate on the phone.  Likely due to the fact, it was not created properly, and/or signed by a root authority that isn't trusted by Android.  Questions with regards to Android devices, specifically Android on a phone, is out of scope here at Superuser.  The following is the description of the Android tag, **"Questions about Android devices are off-topic for Super User and should be asked on android.stackexchange.com unless they specifically involve interaction with a computer."**, and your question isn't is obviously not within scope.

Comment: Why exactly do you believe the certificate in question should require you to provide a password to it?  Any clarification you might have to this question should be included in the question body, clarification made as a comment, is often not really helpful.